# Comparing sum of fixed rate value to sum of escalating value

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Find the number of years, $n$, until the sum of an escalating value/income exceeds the sum of a higher fixed level value/income.

Income fixed at £8405.64

Income escalating @ 3% per annum from £5691.84

$$
8405.64n=5691.84(1+0.03)^n???
$$

Stuck from here, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation only uses the year-to-year value of the escalting income and fails to sum it, which is what the problem requires.

Let $x$ be the fixed income, $y$ be the starting income for the escalating case, and $z$ the rate of growth for the latter. Then what you want to find is $n$ such that

$$
x n < \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}yz^m = y \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}z^m
$$

The term $\sum z^m$ is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), for which there exist known formulas for its value. Specifically, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

**EDIT**:

To solve the above, you need to find the value of $n$ such that

$$
y {{1-z^n}\over{1-z}} - xn > 0,
$$

which I don't think has an analytic solution. Since $n$ can only take integer values, it's probably easiest to just to plug in $n=1,2,\dots$ until the above difference become positive. Another option is to solve graphically. I get the following:

[image]

Comment: How do you inverse this to find a value for n when the sum of the escalating income starts to exceed the sum of the fixed income? Same unknown on both sides of the equation if you make both sides equal

Comment: I don't think you can invert it. You'll probably need to solve it numerically. Note that I fixed an error in the equation as well.